# Multiple findOneAndUpdate operations are being skipped

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `forEach` loop where I am querying a document, doing some simple math calculations and then `updating` a document in the collection and move on to the next iteration.

The problem is, alot of times randomly some of the `UPDATE` operations will not update the document. I don't know why is it happening. Is it because of the `lock`?

I have tried logging things just before the `update` operation. The data is all correct but when it comes to `update`, it will randomly not update at all. Out of 10 iterations, lets say 8 will correctly work

```
    const name = "foo_game";
    players.forEach(({ id, team, username }) => {
      let updatedStats = {};
      Users.findOne({ id }).then(existingPlayer => {
        if (!existingPlayer) return;

        const { stats } = existingPlayer;
        const existingStats = stats[pug.name];

        if (!existingStats) return;
        const presentWins = existingStats.won || 0;
        const presentLosses = existingStats.lost || 0;
        updatedStats = {
          ...existingStats,
          won:
            team === winningTeam
              ? presentWins + 1
              : changeWinner
              ? presentWins - 1
              : presentWins,
          lost:
            team !== winningTeam
              ? presentLosses + 1
              : changeWinner
              ? presentLosses - 1
              : presentLosses,
        };

       // THE CALCULATIONS ARE ALL CORRECT TILL THIS POINT
       // THE UPDATE WIILL RANDOMLY NOT WORK
        Users.findOneAndUpdate(
          { id, server_id: serverId },
          {
            $set: {
              username,
              stats: { ...stats, [name]: updatedStats },
            },
          },
          {
            upsert: true,
          }
        ).exec();
      });
    });
```

Comment: So you are doing a couple of things wrong here, but you also appear to be missing some code. I don't see any declaration of `winningTeam` or where it comes from. Or is this just expected to be a constant of `true` or `false` applied against every player in the array? Same for the `changeWinner` I guess? Could I then basically break down what you want to do as increment/decrement the `won/lost` values under essentially `stats[name]` where `name` is also a set value for the operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you are missing here is the asynchronous operations of both the `findOne()` and the `findOneAndUpdate()` are not guaranteed to complete before your `foreach()` is completed. Using `forEach()` is not a great choice for a loop with async operations in it, but the other main point here is that it's completely unnecessary since MongoDB has a much better way of doing this and in **one** request to the server.

In short, instead of "looping" you actually want to provide an *array of instructions*  to [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/):

```
let server_id = serverId; // Alias one of your variables or just change it's name

Users.bulkWrite(
  players.map(({ id, team, username }) => 
    ({
      "updateOne": {
        "filter": { _id, server_id },
        "update": {
          "$set": { username },
          "$inc": {
            [`stats.${name}.won`]:
              team === winningTeam ?  1 : changeWinner ?  - 1 : 0,
            [`stats.${name}.lost`]:
              team !== winningTeam ?  1 : changeWinner ?  - 1 : 0
          }
        },
        "upsert": true
      }
    })
  )
)
.then(() => /* whatever continuation here */ )
.catch(e => console.error(e))
```

So rather than looping, that `Array.map()` produces one `"updateOne"` statement within the bulk operation for each array member and sends it to the server. The other change of course is you simply do not need the `findOne()` in order to read existing values. All you really need is to use the [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator in order to either *increase* or *decrease* the current value. Noting here that if nothing is currently recorded at the specified path, then it would create those with whatever value of `1/-1/0` was determined by the logic and handed to [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

Note this is how you actually should be doing things in general, as aside from avoiding uneccesary loops of async calls the main thing here is to actually use the atomic operators like [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) that MongoDB has. Reading data state from the database in order to make changes is an *anti-pattern* and best avoided.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will try it out. I am still curious though why this has happened? If you look at it, I am doing `update` after `read` (inside .then) and the `update` will randomly decide to just not work in that iteration.

Comment: @TaranVohra There is nothing "random" about it. Read the opening paragraphs of the answer, where I explain that `foreach()` is not waiting for the asynchronous calls to complete. That's what was really wrong with what you were doing.

Comment: Oh I completely missed that part. Thanks alot. Cleared lot of things.